# How to add a stop execution command in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have to create a batch file which will perform some operation but I need to add some commands so that it will stop execution if it exceeds 30 minutes of execution time.

Can anybody help?
I am new to batch scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Rather you need to call your .bat from another one and check after 30 minutes if it's still running

```
@echo off

set "my_bat=E:\MyBat.bat"

for /f  "delims=" %%a in ('wmic process call create "%my_bat%" ^|find "ProcessId"') do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=;= " %%# in  ("%%a") do set "PID=%%#"
)

::echo %PID%
::sleep for 30 minutes
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1800000 > nul

::kill the bat
tskill %PID% >nul 2>&1
```

you need to change the location of **my_bat** to the yours with full path.

Comment: I realy wish someone write an advanced usage of `call` command for dummys. There is http://ss64.com/nt/call.html this article but its not that good.

Comment: @JohnDOE - SS64 page is much better than the official microsoft help.But  here I've used `WMIC PROCESS CALL CREATE` to acquire the PID of the started process (so later I can kill it without killing all opened command prompts)